# Redefine figure counter with scrbook

Tags: captions, koma-script

I am using the scrbook (KOMA Script) class, as this MWE shows:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper,twoside,BCOR=8mm,DIV=12,headings=normal,open=right]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\begin{document}
\part{Introduction}
\chapter{Lorem ipsum}

\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    My figure here.
    \caption{My caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It's working, by and large, with one exception: The caption reads

> Abbildung 1.: My caption

Notice the superfluous dot before the colon? It's clearly due to using parts; if I stick to chapters and sections only it's formatted as intended.

Any bright ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, the `KOMA-Script` classes will add a period at the end of sectioning numbers, float numbers etc. if a `\part` or `\appendix` command was issued. To counter this behaviour, add the class option `numbers=noendperiod`. See section 3.16 of the `KOMA-Script` manual for further details.

If you want to change the default behaviour *only*  for figure and table captions, add the following to your preamble:

```
\renewcommand*{\figureformat}{%
  \figurename~\thefigure%
%  \autodot% DELETED
}
\renewcommand*{\tableformat}{%
  \tablename~\thetable%
%  \autodot% DELETED
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar.